# Create a side by side plot using imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

I am a beginner in Python and I am having some problems in creating multiple plots.

Right now, I am trying to create two plots side by side using imshow.

What I have attempted so far can be seen below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import rc

data = h5.File('twolevel.h5', 'r')
en_kin = data['1']['energyk'] 
en_pot = data['2']['energyp'] 
psiimag = data['3']['psiimag']
psireal = data['3']['psireal']
time = data['3']['t']
latticex = data['3']['x']
latticey = data['3']['y']

dprof = np.power(psireal[:, :, :], 2) + np.power(psiimag[:, :, :], 2)
l = 400

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.add_subplot(121)
mdr = ax.imshow(dprof[0, :, :], extent=[-l, l, -l, l], interpolation='lanczos',cmap='plasma')
ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_title('t = 0', fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
fig.colorbar(mdr)

ax = plt.add_subplot(122)
mdr = ax.imshow(dprof[1000, :, :], extent=[-l, l, -l, l], interpolation='lanczos',cmap='plasma')
ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
ax.set_title('t = 1000', fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
fig.colorbar(mdr)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The link for the h5 file is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XvGzWIXIgUjWDYcEGHVFw_GHu7NqDdnL?usp=sharing
When I run the script, it returns the following message: **module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'add_subplot'**.

I wonder what is the right way of doing this. Would anyone be able to provide me with an example or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matplotlib documentation is very good, there are a [lot of examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) of how to create subplots.

From the documentation:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```

[image]

You would need to do something like:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.imshow(dprof[0, :, :], extent=[-l, l, -l, l], interpolation='lanczos',cmap='plasma')
ax2.imshow(dprof[1000, :, :], extent=[-l, l, -l, l], interpolation='lanczos',cmap='plasma')
plt.show()
```